# How do i resolve 'Uncaught DOMException: failed to execute add on DOMTokenList:

Tags: javascript, html

I to want create media Icons

```
    <div class="contact">
     <span>
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    </span>
    <span>
     <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </span>
    <span>
     <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
   </span>
   <span>
     <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
   </span>
   <span>
     <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
   </span>
   </div>
```

it works very fine with the above code, using JavaScript function that will do same but I get the error message

**index.js:36 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('fa fa-facebook') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
**

```
let socail = (cls,href) => {
    let sp =document.createElement('span');
    let i = document.createElement('i');
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    sp.prepend(i);
    i.prepend(a);
    i.classList.add(cls);
    a.setAttribute('href', href )
    navImg.insertAdjacentElement('beforeBegin', sp);
};
socail('fa fa-facebook', 'facebook.com');
```

I need assistance on this.

Answer (score 11):

Class names cannot have spaces. The space separates multiple class names.

One thing that you can do is to maintain the multiple classes that you need to add as an array

```
const classesToAdd =['fa','fa-facebook']
socail(classesToAdd, 'facebook.com');
```

and loop through the array items and add them

```
sp.prepend(i);
i.prepend(a);
cls.forEach((ele) => {
    i.classList.add(...cls)
})
```

output:
[image]